# How verify if input is numeric

Tags: php

I have a simple system where this calculation of rates, how to verify if in numerical value is input? I use is_numeric but can  use a only variable, what is alternative?

Show this error: 
Warning: is_nan() expects exactly 1 parameter, 5 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\imposto\processar.php on line 10

follow the code html:

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Calc - Imposto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>SISTEMA DE CÁLCULO DE IMPOSTOS</h2>
<h3>Subistua vírgula por ponto "."</h3>
<form method="POST" action="processar.php">
    <label>Valor Total: </label>
    <input type="text" name="valorTotal" style="width: 100px;"></br></br></br>

    % <input type="text" name="porcentagem1" style="width: 100px;"></br></br>

    % <input type="text" name="porcentagem2" style="width: 100px;"></br></br>

    % <input type="text" name="porcentagem3" style="width: 100px;"></br></br>

    % <input type="text" name="porcentagem4" style="width: 100px;"></br></br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enivar" >


     <input type="reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

follow the code php:

```
<
?php

$valortotal = $_POST['valorTotal'];
$porcentagem1 = $_POST['porcentagem1'];
$porcentagem2 = $_POST['porcentagem2'];
$porcentagem3 = $_POST['porcentagem3'];
$porcentagem4 = $_POST['porcentagem4'];


if(is_numeric($valortotal, $porcentagem1, $porcentagem2, $porcentagem3, $porcentagem4)){
    echo "Por favor, digite apenas números";
}

?>
```

Comment: The alternative is multiple calls to is_numeric, joined together with &&.

Comment: is_numeric() accept only a variable at time so you need if( is_numeric($valortotal) &&  is_numeric($porcentagem1) etc etc

Comment: `<
?php` is that really on 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is_numeric only checks 1 variable.

You have to write a if statement like the following:

```
    if(is_numeric($valortotal) && is_numeric($porcentagem1) && is_numeric($porcentagem2) && is_numeric($porcentagem3) && is_numeric($porcentagem4))
    {
        echo "Por favor, digite apenas números";
    }
```

**Note:** This only echo's "Por favor, digite apenas números" if **all** the variables are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `<?php` is in two lines..
Second the error tells you that the is_numeric expects one parameter you have given it 5.

In order to check all 5 variables you could use the `&&` for every variable so 5 different calls to `is_numeric()` or you could do an array to loop throught and check for every variable if is numeric

```
<?php
$valortotal = $_POST['valorTotal'];
$porcentagem1 = $_POST['porcentagem1'];
$porcentagem2 = $_POST['porcentagem2'];
$porcentagem3 = $_POST['porcentagem3'];
$porcentagem4 = $_POST['porcentagem4'];

$Verify_Int = array(
    $valortotal,
    $porcentagem1,
    $porcentagem2,
    $porcentagem3,
    $porcentagem4
);

foreach ($Verify_Int as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo var_export($element, true) . " is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo var_export($element, true) . " is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```